# This build is parameterized option missing in Jenkins

Tags: jenkins

I'm trying to get a parameterized build running with Jenkins. All the tutorials point to a `This build is parameterized` check box like [here](https://mohamicorp.atlassian.net/wiki/spaces/DOC/pages/210305025/Sending+URL+Parameters+to+Jenkins). Other tutorials point to this [documentation](https://wiki.jenkins.io/display/jenkins/parameterized+build) but after searching around I can't figure out how to get the check box to actually show up. Am I missing something?

Edit: Figured it out - the `This build is parameterized` check box was there all along under a different header. The Office 365 Connector plugin creates a new header that splits the general options in half. I thought that the check box was being used specifically for that plugin, but the header was just misleading.

Comment: You need to install "Parameterzied Build" plugin first.

Comment: How do I do that? It doesn't show up in the list of available plugins in the plugin manager and I can't find an .hpi file to install it manually.

Comment: I just downloaded and installed latest LTS Jenkins, Jenkins 2.235.1 (on my windows machine), didnt install any plugins as part of inital setup. The option of "This project is parameterized" is available out of the box.

Answer (score 4):

If you looking for "This project is parameterised" option that is a native Jenkins functionality. You don't need any plugin for that. It should be under the General tab.

[image]

see my plugins list; I have not installed any plugin.

[image]

Comment: In Jenkins 2.330 we see no `Discard old builds` checkbox (but see a `Discard old items` in its own `Orphaned Item Strategy` tab) and nothing about "arg" or "param" at all.
However Jenkins does draw a `Build with parameters` button, provided the Jenkinsfile declares some parameters.

Comment: Correction to my previous comment: In Jenkins 2.330 (without related plugins) we see `This project is parameterised` via `View Configuration` button at branch level, not any levels above.

Answer (score 0):

In Jenkins 2.330 (without related plugins) we see no option like `This build is parameterized` or `This project is parameterized` at repo level.

Jenkins does draw a `Build with parameters` button for us instead of the usual `Build` button, provided the `Jenkinsfile` declares some parameters.

At branch level, `View Configuration` button then shows a greyed out, enabled checkbox `This project is parameterized` (it is not greyed out in repos where the `Jenkinsfile` declares no parameters, but we opted to configure things at above-repo level so it is not clickable)

**Example Jenkinsfile**:

```
#!groovy

properties([
    parameters([
        booleanParam(name: 'destroy', defaultValue: false,
               description: 'delete images', )
    ])
])

node('normal') {
  if (this.env.destroy == 'true') {
    sh 'echo DESTROY MODE'
  } else {
    sh 'echo DRY RUN'
  }
}
```

Might have to click `Scan Multibranch Pipeline Now` after adding those parameters:

[image: Jenkins buttons]